# How can I convert a string to dictionary in a manner where I have to extract key and value from same string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I need to convert string to dictionary in a manner for example

```
str1 = "00001000-0009efff : a 00100000-656b2fff : b"
```

Output what I require is

```
dict1 = {'a':['00001000','0009efff'], 'b':['00100000','656b2fff']}
```

Note: `str1` can have many more such `c`, `d`, `e` with range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a regex:

```
import re

pattern = r'([\w\-]+) : ([\w\.]+)'
out = {m[1]: m[0].split('-') for m in re.findall(pattern, str1)}
```

Explanation of the regex:

- match combination of alphanumeric characters and dashes `[\w-]+`
- followed by a space, a colon and a space `_:_`
- followed by a combination of alphanumeric characters and dot `[\w\.]+`

The groups are catching your relevant infos.

Comment: if in case str1 = "00001000-0009efff : abc0.0 00100000-656b2fff : xyz1.0"
then it is not giving proper key value, do you know why??

Comment: I think we need pattern as pattern = r'([\w\-]+) : ([\w\.]+)'

Comment: Correct reasoning there. If it is more complex than than, update the question and we can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have a single key letter for each value

```py
str1 = str1.replace(" : ", ":").split(" ")
output = {}
for _, s in enumerate(str1):
    output[s[-1]] = s[:-2].split("-")
```

Comment: Don't use "dict" as a variable name, and why an enumerate if you don't use the enumeration variable ?

Comment: Enumeration is the most "pythonic" way of looping over variables.

Comment: I would upvote without the enumerate.

Comment: where did you heard that ? that is absolutly wrong  just do `for s in str1`

Answer (score 1):

This code will work in general

```
str1 = "00001000-0009efff : a 00100000-656b2fff : b"
needed_dictionary = dict()
split_string = str1.split()

for i in range(len(split_string)):
if split_string[i] == ":":
    needed_dictionary[split_string[i+1]]= split_string[i-1].split("-")
    
print(needed_dictionary)
```

But in Case the values or keys have "-" or ":" in them then this will fail.